# Preciso adicionar legendas a meu gráfico em R

Tags: r, gráfico

```
#--------------Biblioteca necessária para gerar gráficos
library(ggplot2)

#setwd( '/home/gabriel/Videos' )

#-------------------------------Carrega arquivo csv
dados1 <- read.csv(file.choose())
dados2 <- read.csv(file.choose())
dados3 <- read.csv(file.choose())
#head(dados1)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------Calcular taxa de acertos
taxaAcertos1 <- (dados1$acertos / (dados1$acertos + dados1$erros)) * 100
taxaAcertos2 <- (dados2$acertos / (dados2$acertos + dados2$erros)) * 100
taxaAcertos3 <- (dados3$acertos / (dados3$acertos + dados3$erros)) * 100

#head(taxaAcertos)
#-------------------------------------Insere a taxa de acertos ao dataframe
dados1 <- data.frame(dados1,taxaAcertos1)
dados2 <- data.frame(dados2,taxaAcertos2)
dados3 <- data.frame(dados3,taxaAcertos3)
#head(dados1)

#--------------------------------------------range de analize
#---------------------analise do cilco 1 a 26
inicio <- 1
fim <- 26
dados1 <- dados1[inicio:fim,]
dados2 <- dados2[inicio:fim,]
dados3 <- dados3[inicio:fim,]

#Grafico taxa de acertos por cliente ativo

t <- ggplot(data = dados1)
t + geom_line(aes(x = dados1$clientes_ativos, y = dados1$taxaAcertos1, size = dados1$clientes_ativos),
              size = 0.5,colour = 'blue') + 
  geom_point(aes(x = dados1$clientes_ativos, y = dados1$taxaAcertos1, size = dados1$clientes_ativos),shape = 15, colour = 'blue',size = 8) +
  geom_line(aes(x = dados2$clientes_ativos, y = dados2$taxaAcertos2, size = dados2$clientes_ativos),
            size = 0.5,colour = 'red') + 
  geom_point(aes(x = dados2$clientes_ativos, y = dados2$taxaAcertos, size = dados2$clientes_ativos),shape = 17, colour = 'red',size = 7) +
  geom_line(aes(x = dados3$clientes_ativos, y = dados3$taxaAcertos3, size = dados3$clientes_ativos),
            size = 0.5,colour = 'green') +
  geom_point(aes(x = dados3$clientes_ativos, y = dados3$taxaAcertos3, size = dados3$clientes_ativos),shape = 20, colour = 'green',size = 6) +
   ylab("Taxa de Acertos") + xlab("Clientes Ativos") +
```

Quero adicionar legendas as cores e aumentar o tamnho das letras do eixo x e y

[image: Gráfico]

Comment: Eu desconfio que esta pergunta não está recebendo muita atenção porque os dados não estão disponíveis no post. Portanto, o teu exemplo não é reproduzível. Talvez seja interessante editar a pergunta com o resultado dos comandos `dput(dados1)`, `dput(dados2)` e `dput(dados3)` para facilitar a vida de quem, porventura, tenha conhecimento suficiente para te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Para aumentar as letras do eixo x e y é a função `theme` . Vale lembrar que o `text` é relacionado ao texto do eixo e o `title`ao título do eixo. Basta variar o `size`a se encaixar melhor.

`theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16),
                      axis.text.y = element_text(size = 18),
                      axis.title.x = element_text(size = 20),
                      axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20))`

Para adicionar a legenda basta usar:

`scale_color_manual ("Título da Legenda", 
                      breaks = c("Dados 1", "Dados 2", "Dados 3"),
                      values = c("blue", "red", "green"))`

Para gráficos futuros recomendo fazer uma única planilha, pios o `ggplot` já reconhece e cria automaticamente as legendas de forma correta. Você pode usar o comando `rbind`.